# how to select any href using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

The following code is used for my sidebar to be able to set the active subpage and properly display the the sidebar when refreshing the page.

It works well if I add the "#" symbol to the href of the subpages but didn't work when changing the href to anything else and removing the "#" symbol. Let's suppose I want to set the href as "/contactpage/. How do I indicate in the below code to choose any href not only the ones that contains the hash symbol?

```
  <script>

      (() => {
        'use strict'
      
      
      
        function setActiveItem() {
          const { hash } = window.location
      
          if (hash === '') {
            return
          }
      
          const link = document.querySelector(`.d-flex a[href="${hash}"]`)
      
          if (!link) {
            return
          }
      
          const active = document.querySelector('.d-flex .active')
          const parent = link.parentNode.parentNode.previousElementSibling
      
          link.classList.add('active')
      
          if (parent.classList.contains('collapsed')) {
            parent.click()
          }
      
          if (!active) {
            return
          }
      
          const expanded = active.parentNode.parentNode.previousElementSibling
      
          active.classList.remove('active')
      
          if (expanded && parent !== expanded) {
            expanded.click()
          }
        }
      
        setActiveItem()
        window.addEventListener('hashchange', setActiveItem)
      })()
      
      
      
      </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Select anything with an "href" attribute, regardless of its value
document.querySelectorAll('[href]')

// Select only the first link with the current page's path ("active" link)
const currentPath = window.location.pathname
document.querySelector(`a[href="${currentPath}"]`)

// Select the currently active path including the hash
const currentPathWithHash = window.location.pathname + window.location.hash
document.querySelector(`a[href="${currentPathWithHash}"]`)
```

To avoid issues when none of the links contain hashes, just remove the first few lines of your code up to `const link = ...`, which should be replaced by one of the options above (edit to suit your needs).

I also noticed that if `active` is also the current link, you'll end up first adding the `active` class to it and deleting it later in your code. Switch the order like this to avoid that:

```js
active.classList.remove('active')
link.classList.add('active')
```

Note that if there could be more than one link on the page that point to the current path, you should probably add further selectors, like a class name you use for the target links. Unless of course you want to target any link with that path, in which case just use `document.querySelectorAll`. Yours seem to be under a `.d-flex` container, so add that to my examples.

Comment: I tried the first one with "document.querySelectorAll('[href]')", however it doesn't work. When refreshing the page the subpages are no more active , the sidebar should be collapsed when refreshing the page

Comment: @rhelminin - the hashchange event may affect it? at the bottom is this line of code: window.addEventListener('hashchange', setActiveItem)

Comment: Yeah, that probably doesn't fire on page reloads, but I haven't tested, so don't quote me on that! :) I usually just use the `DOMContentLoaded` event to check for new page loads, although if you're using anything like React, Vue, Turbolinks etc (anything that makes it so that navigation doesn't trigger a full page reload), you might need to use something else. Oh, and if you need to check for the search params and hash in your url as well, you could use `location.href.replace(location.origin, '')` to get the current path with those included.

Comment: I use flask for this application. It is not about window.addEvenListener because I deleted it and there is no problem when using the hash symbol. The issue is with the first lines of codes:         function setActiveItem() {
          const { hash } = window.location
      
          if (hash === '') {
            return
          }
      
          const link = document.querySelector(`.d-flex a[href="${hash}"]`)
      
          if (!link) {
            return
          }

Comment: @rhelminim - everything works just perfect when the submenu links contain '#' symbol in href, but without it it simply doesn't work, when I refresh the page the sidebar doesn't collapse... I am stuck in this for 8 hours already

Comment: Ah yes, that will mess things up, as `if (hash === '') { return }` will stop the function execution right at the beginning if your sidebar doesn't contain any links with hashes. I added some clarifications and additional information to my original answer, see if those help! :)